# Error by import numpy: lapack_lite.so: undefined symbol

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, numpy

After my Kubuntu (x86) has upgraded to 14.04, I got numpy not working in python 2.7:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/prylipko/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/home/prylipko/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/prylipko/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from polynomial import *
  File "/home/prylipko/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 17, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq
  File "/home/prylipko/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from linalg import *
  File "/home/prylipko/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 23, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite
ImportError: /home/prylipko/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so: undefined symbol: ATL_cpttrsm
```

I tried almost everything. Tried to re-install numpy (using pip), ATLAS, and LAPACK. I also tried to build numpy from sources, specifying the proper fortran compiler (gfortran=gnu95) used to build ATLAS.

Unfortunately, nothing helps. Could somebody suggest a recipe to fix it?
I believe, I am not the only one in the Universe facing this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like something probably went wrong during the ATLAS build process, beyond that these things are rather tricky to troubleshoot. You might find [this guide](http://mbudisic.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/installing-atlas-with-full-lapack-on-64-bit-linux/) helpful. I'd also highly recommend using [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/) instead of ATLAS - in my experience it's been faster and way less fiddly to compile.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Using OpenBLAS did help. I found a guide for installing numpy/scipy with OpenBLAS here: http://osdf.github.io/blog/numpyscipy-with-openblas-for-ubuntu-1204-second-try.html

Comment: I also wrote step-by-step instructions in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14391693/1461210). Leave a comment if you run into problems.

Comment: It's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/atlas/+bug/1336202).

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this same error, running Python 2.7.3 under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

An August 14 comment posted on the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/atlas/+bug/1336202) noted in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612728/error-by-import-numpy-lapack-lite-so-undefined-symbol#comment39229076_23612728) above by [Roland Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219295/roland-smith) suggested the following solution, which worked for me:

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```