# Installing Numpy with OpenBLAS support in home directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, installation, openblas

I'm installing a Python (2.7.8) environment locally in my home folder on a server, in order to use newer versions of Python and some of its libraries (Numpy, Theano) together with OpenBLAS. For this, I first installed Python in the folder `usr` in my home directory (`/home/my_home/usr/`) as described here:

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2002-March/012903.html

The installation seems to have gone smoothly. I checked this by starting the Python interpreter, which displays the right version on startup.

Following this, I installed OpenBLAS into `/home/my_home/opt` folder as described here:

[Compiling numpy with OpenBLAS integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443302/compiling-numpy-with-openblas-integration)

... which also didn't give me any errors. However, now when I try installing Numpy (according to the instructions in the above link), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/home/ext_sxc/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 427, in <module>
    import select
ImportError: No module named select
```

I suppose the straightforward thing to do is to find the package for `select`, compile and install it. I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do because the last time I installed Python 2.7.6 locally in a home directory, there were no such errors. As I understand, the `select` module should have been installed along with Python.

This also happens when I try installing IPython in a similar way in my home folder. The library which gives the `ImportError` is different.

I'm wondering if these are related to a more general mistake I may have made while installing Python. I'd appreciate any advice on this issue. Please let me know if any additional information would help. Thanks!