# Numpy with Blas and OpenBlas take the same time

Tags: python, numpy, openblas

I install `Numpy` (in a virtualenv `env`) with `OpenBlas` (from the system).

```
$ sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev
(env)$  mkdir evn/download
(env)$ pip install -d env/download numpy
(env)$ mkdir env/build
(env)$ cd env/build
(env)$ tar xzf ../download/numpy-1.9.2.tar.gz
(env)$ cd numpy-1.9.2
```

Edit the `site.cfg`:

```
[atlas]
atlas_libs = openblas
libraries = openblas

[openblas]
libraries = openblas
library_dirs = /usr/lib/openblas-base/
```

And then, install `numpy` using `pip`. Additionally, install `numpy` via system (with `blas`). I test the times with this [scrpit](https://gist.github.com/osdf/3842524#file_test_numpy.py). In both case, I have the same time. I check, and the system use `Blas` and the virtualenv use `OpenBlas`.  Why it takes the same time?

I use Debian testing, and python 2.7.9

Answer (score 0):

If you use `pip` to install `numpy`, I believe that will build it without OpenBLAS support, no matter what you put in the `site.cfg` file.

You have to explicitly call  `python setup.py build` etc. You can follow for instance this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14391693/1791279) for the installation guide.