# Numpy multiarray.so: undefined symbol: cblas_sgemm

Tags: python, numpy, opensuse, blas, atlas

I'm trying to install `numpy==1.10.2`, `scipy` and `matplotlib` on server based on `opensuse`.
I've installed `numpy` in `virtualenv` from source (I've tried by pip also - same result of course). Now when I'm trying to import `numpy` in python console I'm receiving following error:

```
ImportError: /home/user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: cblas_sgemm
```

Note: I'm not superuser on this server.

Edit:

```
ldd /home/user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so`
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffa0d69000)
libtatlas.so.3 => /home/user/.local/usr/lib64/atlas/libtatlas.so.3 (0x00007fe366d66000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe366a50000)
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007fe3666b2000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe366496000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe3660f0000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe367a15000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe365eec000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fe365ce9000)
```

`libtatlas.so.3 => /home/user/.local/usr/lib64/atlas/libtatlas.so.3` - I linked this because of other problem with libatlas:
`ImportError: /usr/lib64/atlas/libtatlas.so.3: undefined symbol: clapack_ilaenv`

**SOLLUTION**

The problem was with ATLAS lib. According to @ali_m advice I installed `numpy` from source with `OpenBLAS` instead of ATLAS. [Here link to instruction how to install numpy with BLAS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443302/compiling-numpy-with-openblas-integration/14391693#14391693)

Comment: What BLAS library are you linked against? Could you show the output of `$ ldd /home/user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so`?

Comment: I've edited original post with output from ldd

Comment: Hmm... Did you compile that ATLAS library yourself? IIRC, building ATLAS is quite a fiddly process, so I suppose it's possible that something went wrong. I would recommend using OpenBLAS instead - it's much easier to compile, and is consistently faster than ATLAS in every benchmark I've come across so far.

Comment: Ok. ATLAS compilation looks pretty hard. How should I use BLAS with numpy? I don't know anything about this libraries...

Comment: Well, where did that ATLAS library in `/home/user/.local/usr/lib64/atlas/libtatlas.so.3` come from if you didn't build it yourself?

Comment: You could look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14391693/1461210) if you just want instructions for building numpy and OpenBLAS

Comment: I unpacked this lib from rpm package... A little workaround. I will try to compile it tomorrow. Thank you very much for help :)

Comment: On the version of ATLAS installed on my Ubuntu machine the `clapack_` and `cblas_` symbols are defined in another library called `liblapack_atlas.so`. That might come from another RPM package (if you were able to install using your system package manager then it ought to sort out these dependencies for you automatically). Anyway, I would recommend OpenBLAS over ATLAS.

Comment: You rock @ali_m ! Your advice about installing numpy with BLAS helped me and now everything works well :) Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments above, you extracted `libtatlas.so.3` from an RPM package and copied it into a local directory, rather than either building it from source or installing it via the package manager. I'm sure that this is the cause of the problem.

In particular, the `clapack_*` and `cblas_*` symbols don't seem to be defined within `libtatlas.so.3`. On my Ubuntu machine, if I `sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev` I get two different shared libraries:

```
~$ ldconfig -p | grep atlas
        liblapack_atlas.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/liblapack_atlas.so.3
        liblapack_atlas.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/liblapack_atlas.so
        libatlas.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libatlas.so.3
        libatlas.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libatlas.so
```

The `clapack_*` and `cgemm_*` symbols are defined in `liblapack_atlas.so.3` rather than `libatlas_so.3`:

```
~$ nm -D /usr/lib/libatlas.so.3 | grep clapack_ilaenv

~$ nm -D /usr/lib/libatlas.so.3 | grep cblas_sgemm

~$ nm -D /usr/lib/liblapack_atlas.so.3 | grep clapack_ilaenv
0000000000041d90 T clapack_ilaenv

~$ nm -D /usr/lib/liblapack_atlas.so.3 | grep cblas_sgemm
                 U cblas_sgemm
```

Given that you have no admin rights, and therefore can't install ATLAS via the normal system package manager, here are three potential solutions:

- It *might* be possible to extract a binary of `liblapack_atlas.so.3` (or whatever the OpenSUSE equivalent is) from a different RPM package, and get numpy to link against it by modifying the `site.cfg` file in the numpy source directory.
- Another option would be to [build ATLAS from source](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/atlas_install/), but in my experience this is a long and painful process.
- My personal recommendation would be to build OpenBLAS instead, as described in my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14391693/1461210). It's much easier to compile, and has better performance in every benchmark that I've come across so far.