# numpy installation into pypy3 virtual env : `undefined symbol: cblas_sgemm`

Tags: numpy, installation, pypy

I am trying to install numpy into a pypy3 virtualenv, but I'm stuck with that error (at importing) :

```
venv_pypy/site-packages/numpy-1.16.0.dev0+1d38e41-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.pypy3-60-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: cblas_sgemm
```

I am on an up to date archlinux, numpy works fine with CPython, but I have a project using pandas (which depends on numpy) that I need to test on pypy.

I first tried the recommended method (`pip install numpy` in the venv) but didn't work. (install is fine, but still the same error at execution).

I then, I tried what is suggested https://stackoverflow.com/a/14391693/1745291 (linked from [Numpy multiarray.so: undefined symbol: cblas_sgemm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34619752/1745291) ), since I didn't installed ATLAS (aur package on arch I don't want to install), to try building with OpenBias. But still not working (same error, and the method could be outdated since it's from 2013)

...And finally, I tried a build with no accelerations (at least, that is claimed) following : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/building.html#disabling-atlas-and-other-accelerated-libraries
...But still the same result...

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try uninstall it from pip and install from apt (if you are using ubuntu etc.)

This approach solved my problem

```
pip3 uninstall numpy
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

Comment: The question was about numpy for pypy, and not cpython.