# Problems with installing scipy with pip on Windows?

Tags: python, scipy

I have started working on python, and now, I want to solve real scientific problems for which SciPy is required.
I have tried to install SciPy with:

> pip install scipy-0.16.0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl

and I got message that SciPy is installed successfully. However, when I want to import SciPy the error is:

> raise ImportError("Numpy OpenBLAS flavour is needed for this scipy  build.")
>   ImportError: Numpy OpenBLAS flavour is needed for this scipy build.

I am using Windows OS, and I am using Eclipse+PyDev as an IDE. What makes this sort of problem? And how can I solve it?

Comment: I had also same issue, did you solve it by yourself ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to install NumPy which is an requirement for SciPy?

You can download it here: [Python Packages For Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

Comment: Yes! NumPy is installed. I was using it for a while.

Comment: What about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443302/compiling-numpy-with-openblas-integration

Comment: It seems this is for linux?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the wheel for numpy with OpenBLAS from https://pypi.anaconda.org/carlkl/simple/numpy/

Comment: What is the version of numpy with OpenBLAS ? I don't think that this link refers to these versions.

Comment: That link has up to numpy 1.10.0b1. I got scipy 0.16.0 working in Python 3.3 on Win-AMD-64 by using the numpy-1.10.0b1-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl. Try that and if you get errors maybe open a new question.