# Numpy dot operation is not using all cpu cores

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.5, openblas

- I am doing numpy dot product on two matrices (Let us assume a and b are two matrices).
- When the shape of a is (10000, 10000) and shape of b is (1, 10000) then the numpy.dot(a, b.T) is using all the CPU cores.
- But when the shape of a is (10000, 10000) and shape of b is (2, 10000) then the numpy.dot(a, b.T) is not using all the CPU cores (Only using one).

This is happening when the row size of b is from 2 to 15 (i.e from (2, 10000) to (15, 10000)).

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10**4, 10**4)

def dot(a, b_row_size):
    b = np.random.rand(b_row_size, 10**4)

    for i in range(10):
        # dot operation
        x = np.dot(a, b.T)

# Using all CPU cores
dot(a, 1)

# Using only one CPU core
dot(a, 2)

# Using only one CPU core
dot(a, 5)

# Using only one CPU core
dot(a, 15)

# Using all CPU cores
dot(a, 16)

# Using all CPU cores
dot(a, 50)
```

**np.show_config()**

```
openblas_lapack_info:
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
lapack_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Numpy dot operation is not using all cpu cores

numpy.show_config() is clearly showing that it is using OpenBLAS at underline level.

So OpenBLAS is the actual one that is responsible for parallel computation.

But in `sgemm` OpenBLAS won't parallelize the computation up to certain threshold (In your case the row size of b is 2 to 15).

As a workaround, you can change the threshold value (**GEMM_MULTITHREAD_THRESHOLD**) in [sgemm](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/blob/develop/interface/gemm.c#L75) file and [compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443302/compiling-numpy-with-openblas-integration/14391693#14391693) the OpenBLAS with numpy

Change the **GEMM_MULTITHREAD_THRESHOLD** value from **4** to **0** to parallelize all the `sgemm` computations.

Comment: Are there any good heuristics on when it is worth to change the GEMM_MULTITHREAD_THRESHOLD? I guess there is a reason why it defaults to 4...