# Python: Vectorizing Matrix Multiplications in the Loops?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have an N-by-M array, at each entry of whom, I need to do some NumPy operations and put the result there.

Right now, I'm doing it the naive way with a double loop:

```
import numpy as np

N = 10
M = 11
K = 100

result = np.zeros((N, M))

is_relevant = np.random.rand(N, M, K) > 0.5
weight = np.random.rand(3, 3, K)
values1 = np.random.rand(3, 3, K)
values2 = np.random.rand(3, 3, K)

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        selector = is_relevant[i, j, :]
        result[i, j] = np.sum(
            np.multiply(
                np.multiply(
                    values1[..., selector],
                    values2[..., selector]
                ), weight[..., selector]
            )
        )
```

Since all the in-loop operations are simply NumPy operations, I think there must be a way to do this faster or loop-free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a combination of `np.einsum` and `np.tensordot` -

```
a = np.einsum('ijk,ijk,ijk->k',values1,values2,weight)
out = np.tensordot(a,is_relevant,axes=(0,2))
```

Alternatively, with one `einsum` call -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ijk,ijk,lmk->lm',values1,values2,weight,is_relevant)
```

And with `np.dot` and `einsum` -

```
is_relevant.dot(np.einsum('ijk,ijk,ijk->k',values1,values2,weight))
```

Also, play around with the `optimize` flag in `np.einsum` by setting it as `True` to use BLAS.

Timings -

```
In [146]: %%timeit
     ...: a = np.einsum('ijk,ijk,ijk->k',values1,values2,weight)
     ...: out = np.tensordot(a,is_relevant,axes=(0,2))
10000 loops, best of 3: 121 µs per loop

In [147]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,ijk,ijk,lmk->lm',values1,values2,weight,is_relevant)
1000 loops, best of 3: 851 µs per loop

In [148]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,ijk,ijk,lmk->lm',values1,values2,weight,is_relevant,optimize=True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 347 µs per loop

In [156]: %timeit is_relevant.dot(np.einsum('ijk,ijk,ijk->k',values1,values2,weight))
10000 loops, best of 3: 58.6 µs per loop
```

#### Very large arrays

For very large arrays, we can leverage `numexpr` to make use of `multi-cores` -

```
import numexpr as ne

a = np.einsum('ijk,ijk,ijk->k',values1,values2,weight)
out = np.empty((N, M))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        out[i,j] = ne.evaluate('sum(is_relevant_ij*a)',{'is_relevant_ij':is_relevant[i,j], 'a':a})
```

Comment: .. `(np.all(out == result) --> False`

Comment: @wwii We are dealing with floating pt numbers. So, it's better to use `np.allclose()`.

Comment: Gets me every time.

Comment: Wow, that `einsum` one-liner is just gold -- much cleaner and clearer!

Comment: When my K is very big (560,000), and N and M are much smaller (like 100), even the `np.dot and einsum` method runs as slowly as my double loop. Is there a faster method for such cases (huge K)?

Comment: ^ I found my `np.dot` in this case was just using a single core. Investigating why now. But I've checked my numpy is able to use multiple cores with MKL when executing `A = np.random.rand(30000,30000); B = np.dot(A, A)`.

Comment: @SibbsGambling Please check out edit at the end - `Very large arrays`. Would like to know the kind of speedups you might be getting with it. `MKL` should help too. Let me know if you get any boost with it.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get a 2x speed up with `numexpr`, but I'm still obsessed as to why my `np.dot` is using just one core for this case (it uses all cores when doing `A = np.random.rand(30000,30000); B = np.dot(A, A)`!). Should I open another question on this?

Comment: @SibbsGambling This might be relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295180/? Feel free to ask a new one, if that doesn't answer it.

Comment: Tried many other ways and different combinations of these approaches and found `numexpr` is really hard to beat, even with parallel threads that already have communication overhead minimized. Will go with this with large `K`, and the `einsum` one-liner for small `K`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another very simple option is just:

```
result = (values1 * values2 * weight * is_relevant[:, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]).sum((2, 3, 4))
```

[Divakar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56188935/1782792) last solution is faster than this though. Timings for comparison:

```
%timeit np.tensordot(np.einsum('ijk,ijk,ijk->k',values1,values2,weight),is_relevant,axes=(0,2))
# 30.9 µs ± 1.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit np.einsum('ijk,ijk,ijk,lmk->lm',values1,values2,weight,is_relevant)
# 379 µs ± 486 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit np.einsum('ijk,ijk,ijk,lmk->lm',values1,values2,weight,is_relevant,optimize=True)
# 145 µs ± 1.89 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit is_relevant.dot(np.einsum('ijk,ijk,ijk->k',values1,values2,weight))
# 15 µs ± 124 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit (values1 * values2 * weight * is_relevant[:, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]).sum((2, 3, 4))
# 152 µs ± 1.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```