# Can't get Python3 numpy to see BLAS/LAPACK

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian, lapack, blas

I'm running **Linaro Debian Stretch** on a **Tinkerboard** and I can't seem to be able to get **numpy** on **Python3** to see any installed **BLAS/LAPACK** resources.

Running `np.__config__.show()` under **python3** gives `NOT AVAILABLE` for every single entry.

I've installed the **BLAS/LAPACK** via `sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev`, and `python3-numpy` and `python3-scipy` via apt-get as well. **Numpy** and **scipy** both run perfectly fine. I've also installed **ATLAS** and **OpenBLAS** without luck, and have tried manual compilation of **OpenBLAS** and **numpy** too. Nothing changes the output of `np.__config__.show()`.

**Python2**, however, shows that these resources are installed.

How can I get **Python3** to see these resources too?

Comment: Which Debian version is this?

Comment: Downloaded from the tinkerboard website: https://tinkerboarding.co.uk/forum/thread-69.html

20180622-tinker-board-linaro-stretch-alip-v2.0.7.img.zip

Comment: I vaguely remember that at one point, `python-numpy` and `python3-numpy` depended on different versions of BLAS for some reason, so you had to install `libblas` and also the backward-compat `libblas2`, or something like that, if you wanted both of them to use BLAS.

Comment: OK, so the version is Stretch. You should probably [edit] that into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's interested in the answer, I managed to finally get OpenBLAS recognized in numpy, and received a decent speed boost.

To do it you must first uninstall python3-numpy and any numpy installed via pip3. Then manually compile OpenBLAS and numpy as explained in [Compiling numpy with OpenBLAS integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443302/compiling-numpy-with-openblas-integration).

Installing the default packages via apt-get or pip apparently doesn't seem to link in any BLAS library by default, at least not on the TinkerBoard Linaro OS...